# How to check if 'x' or 'o' occurs at least in one column?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, tic-tac-toe

I made a tic tac toe game and I want to check if 'x' or 'o' occurs in an entire column or a row, the game-board is a 3X3-matrix .
I wrote down a code that implements that (the column part), but the problem is that the loop is only counting the first column.
output:
[image]
the first column is counted, and x had won.

[image]
even if the column is full with 'x', x doesn't win and the game continues.

*Notes:* It is designated for x for purpose. In the output, o is at index 2,2 through the rest of the game for testing purposes.

Here's my code:

```
int win(char board[][COL])
{
    int flag = 0;
    int x = 0, o = 0;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < COL; i++) // this loop checks who won by fillin a column
    {
        if (board[i][j] == 'x')
        {
            x++;
        }
        if (x == COL)
        {
            flag = 1;
            printf("x won!\n");
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Comment: why is `j` always `0`?

Comment: I don't get your whole approach. Why compare `x` with `COL` inside the loop? What is the function supposed to do? And for TTT, you have to check rows, columns and diagonals. Here you just check the first **row**, but the flag cannot be set. Use your debugger to see what actually happens in the code, it will be a good training!

Comment: @olaf COL's value is 3, that if-statement was for checking if x is in a column 3 times (COL times). I (partially and probably discreetly) stated that it supposed to cover the column part... I'm sorry for the inconvenience, thank you for your concern.

Comment: Sorry, I confused cols and rows. But the condition **cannot** be true inside the loop! You should re-read the chapter about the `for` loop in your C book.

Answer (score 0):

You are just checking for first column.

```
int win(char board[][COL])
{
    int flag = 0;
    int x = 0, o = 0;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for(j = 0; j < 3 ; j++)
    {
       x=0;
       for (i = 0; i < COL; i++) // this loop checks who won by fillin a column
       {
           if (board[i][j] == 'x')
           {
               x++;
           }
           if (x == COL)
           {
               flag = 1;
               printf("x won!\n");
           }
       }
    }
    return flag;
}
```